# How to focus the camera to rotate around spots in SCULPT mode?

Tags: sculpting

I'm sculpting for the first time and instantly ran into a problem, that I faced before on Edit mode. When I navigate, zoom and rotate to different spots, the camera sometimes gets too far away from its origin/pivot point and turns too fast and uncontrollably around the place I'm working on.

I solved this problem on Edit mode, once I found out about the Num,/Del key, which focuses the camera on the active vertices to allow camera navigation around them. However this doesn't work on Sculpt mode.

So I'm in the need of a similar solution for the Sculpt mode. This problem is especially bad when using a drawing tablet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same key (numpad ./del) will focus on the last part your cursor touched. This *does* mean you need to click somewhere for it to work, but the only other way I know of is to lock your view to the cursor (in the view>view lock tab of the sidebar) which is a bit more finicky.

Comment: The first solution works well enough. Didn't knew about it, I thought the Del couldn't be used on Sculpt mode at all. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Then please mark this question answered.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Follow the steps and you will be able to navigate like ZBrush. I mean at the center of each place you select in the sculpt mode